# ListViews inside Fragments inside FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm getting very confused over how to implement ListViews inside a fragment controlled through a FragmentPagerAdapter.

At the moment i'm attempting to return some JSON data, and depending on a value within the JSON separate the data into 3 individual lists; 'Loan', 'Reservations' and 'Booked'. This is like the TeamTreehouse exercise 'Build a Blog Reader Android App', and i have attempted to expand upon it to further my education regarding Android.

I started having issues when i tried to implement Fragments. From my understanding Fragments are reusable elements with their own activity lifecycle, so it seemed perfect to implement a fragment containing all the logic and then simply pull the information i required into separate lists using a FragmentPagerAdapter. The only problem is that the ListView is not being displayed, although the information is being pulled through in LogCat. I've spent days reading and researching this problem, and i think it may have something to do with how i am implementing my ListView within the Fragment, but I could really do with some help.

I have included code for my Fragment class which i have called 'LoanFragment', as well as the FragmentPagerAdapter 'LibraryPagerAdapter' and my 'Library' class from which the FragmentPagerAdapter is called:

```
public class LoanFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lv;
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "Title";
    private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "Author";
    public static final String TAG = Library.class.getSimpleName();
    protected JSONArray mTasksData; 
    SessionManager session; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.booked_fragment, container, false);

        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listMe);

        bindListView();

        return rootView;

    }

    public void bindListView() {
        new GetLibraryInformation(getActivity(),lv).execute("");
     }


    class GetLibraryInformation extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONArray> {
        ListView mListView;
        Activity mContext;


        public GetLibraryInformation(Activity context,ListView gview) {
                    this.mListView=gview;
                    this.mContext=context;
            }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
            JSONArray jsonResponse = null;

            // Get JSON data, all coming through fine
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {        
            mTasksData = result;
            String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            String author = "";
            String title = "";
            List<HashMap<String, String>> fetch2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            if(mTasksData == null) {

            }
            else {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mTasksData.length(); i++) {     
                        JSONObject task = mTasksData.getJSONObject(i);

                        if(task.has(KEY_TITLE)) {                       
                            title = task.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            title = "Title not set.";
                        }   

                        if(task.has(KEY_AUTHOR)) {                      
                            author = task.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
                        }
                        else {
                            author = "Author not set.";
                        }                       

                        HashMap<String, String> libraryInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        libraryInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        libraryInfo.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                        libraryInfo.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);

                        fetch2.add(libraryInfo);

                    }

                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), fetch2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);   

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                catch(JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught! ", e);
                }
            }

        }
    }       
}
```

This is my FragmentPagerAdapater, from which i understand should return each separate Fragment (at the moment they all look like LoanFragment):

```
public class LibraryPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public LibraryPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:     
            return new LoanFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ReservationFragment();
        case 2:
            return new BookedFragment();
        default:
             return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

And my Library, extending FragmentActivity:

```
public class Library extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private LibraryPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private String[] tabs = { "Loan", "Reservation", "Booked" };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new LibraryPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        }); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tasks, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

And finally the 'booked_fragment.xml', which i am trying to use to display the ListView:

The FragmentPagerAdapter are both using the same Fragment import (android.support.v4.app.Fragment), but the application, aside from the tabs being present, is just returning totally blank!

Any help would be massively appreciated as i'm starting to turn into a turnip here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

     <ListView android:id="@+id/listMe"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:background="#f9f9f9"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
               />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an misunderstanding about the layout which is to be passed to SimpleAdapter.
In your call to the constructor  (Context context, List> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) you need to pass the layout for a list item, not of the layout containing the ListView itself.
As the items are displayed in the ListView and dynamically added, the SimpleAdapter expects this layout to be known (and passed). If you compare it to a table, e.g.: The layout you are using defines the layout for the table, the layout for the list items defines on how one row in that table should look like.

Comment: thank you Peter, i'd just noticed i'd put that in wrong now and edited it so instead of using booked_fragments it now uses androids simple_list_item_2, but the list is still not showing :/

Comment: Could you post the  simple_list_item_2.xml? And please assure that fetch2.size() != 0.

Comment: indeed, the source for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2.xml is located here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml

and fetch2 is definitely not empty in logcat.

thank you!

Comment: fetch2 looks like this in logcat:
fetch2 
[{Author=Clue State, Title=Introduction to introductions}, 
{Author=Boris Randon, Title=Forrest Gump 2: The Awakening}, 
{Author=Author not set., Title=Joan of Arc}]

Comment: sorry to waste your time Peter, for some reason the text was defaulting to white on a white background :E i feel very stupid right now

Comment: Don't have to. Sometimes it's funny, what a second overviewing does. As I mostly use self - implemented adapters, because the items in hte List are user - defined object types, there is no problem in downtracing the issue. When using a third - party - adapter it always ends up with the question: Am I doing something wrong? Where? is the third - party - component working properyl?